# Make a scrollbar update another scrollbar and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given the following [js-bin](https://jsbin.com/korewetedu/4/edit?html,js,output), how can I do such that, if I scroll in the `left` div (using mouse wheel) it will update in the `right` div.

This works, but if you uncomment the code it will not scroll by 100px at mouse wheel (default chrome mouse wheel behaviour) anymore. (It will scroll pixel by pixel, which is something I don't want).

Basically I need to keep the default chrome mouse wheel scroll behaviour.

```html
        const target = $("#target");
        $("#source").on("scroll", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          target
            .prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
            .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
       console.log("Called.")
        });
  
//    $("#target").on("scroll", function (e) {
//           e.preventDefault()
//           $("#source")
//             .prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
//             .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
//        console.log("Called.")
//         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for a *Next Tick* using a `setTimeout()` and modify your code like:

```js
const $scrollers = $("#target, #source");
let tickTimeout = null;

$scrollers.on("scroll", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const self = this;
  const $other = $scrollers.not(self);

  clearTimeout(tickTimeout);
  tickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    $other.prop({
      scrollLeft: self.scrollLeft,
      scrollTop: self.scrollTop,
    });
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
.scroll-example {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll the left div, watch the right one.</p>
<div id="target" class="scroll-example">
  1<br />2 <br />3 <br />4 <br />5 <br />6 <br />7 <br />8 <br />9 <br />10<br />11 <br />12 <br />13 <br />14 <br />15 <br />16 <br />17 <br />18<br />19 <br />20
</div>
<div id="source" class="scroll-example">
  1<br />2 <br />3 <br />4 <br />5 <br />6 <br />7 <br />8 <br />9 <br />10<br />11 <br />12 <br />13 <br />14 <br />15 <br />16 <br />17 <br />18<br />19 <br />20
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its solves my problem, but can you explain it a bit more? How does a timeout with 0ms, solve this problem?

Comment: Is it cause of this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event? But I still don't get it how it works :\

Comment: @JohnDoe the scroll triggers too many times and clutters, but my main reasoning was to actually wait for that scroll to happen, assign a function to the queue (https://medium.com/@Rahulx1/understanding-event-loop-call-stack-event-job-queue-in-javascript-63dcd2c71ecd) and finally update the other elements scrollTop value.